# DotNet app Deployment fails on Kubernetes but runs fine on Docker

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Playing around with a small app to test out Kubernetes, secrets and the like.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["KubernetesTestWithSecrets/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.csproj", "KubernetesTestWithSecrets/"]
RUN dotnet restore "KubernetesTestWithSecrets/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/KubernetesTestWithSecrets"
RUN dotnet build "KubernetesTestWithSecrets.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "KubernetesTestWithSecrets.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.dll"]
```

`docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  test:
    restart: "always"
    image: privateRepoServerUri:5001/path/kubernetestestwithsecrets:latest
    ports:
      - 9443:9443
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./ssl:/ssl:ro
```

If I fire this off then all is good n golden the host fires up and waits for further instruction.

*However* when it comes to Kubernetes, it not so happy...

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kubernetestestwithsecrets
  name: kubernetestestwithsecrets
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kubernetestestwithsecrets
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kubernetestestwithsecrets
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: quay-at-myprivateregistry
      containers:
        - name: kubernetestestwithsecrets
          image: privateRepoServerUri:5001/path/kubernetestestwithsecrets:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          volumeMounts:
            - name: volume-key-pfx
              mountPath: /app/ssl
              readOnly: true
            - name: volume-secret-appsettings-json
              mountPath: /app/private
              readOnly: true
            - name: volume-appsettings-json
              mountPath: /app
              readOnly: false
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: volume-appsettings-json
          configMap:
            name: configmap-appsettings.json
        - name: volume-secret-appsettings-json
          secret:
            secretName: secret-secret-appsettings.json
        - name: volume-key-pfx
          secret:
            secretName: secret-key.pfx

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kubernetestestwithsecrets-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: kubernetestestwithsecrets
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - name: port-80
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30080
    - name: port-443
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      nodePort: 30443
```

Yields abject failure with `kubectl logs kubernetestestwithsecrets-(random)` giving me:

```
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:
  * You intended to execute a .NET application:
      The application '/app/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.dll' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      No .NET SDKs were found.

Download a .NET SDK:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/download

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found
```

I've triple and quintuple checked the container etc., both within and without and the files are all there. It's pulling the repo fine and going into `minikube` ssh I can do the same thing there.

What obviousness am I missing here?

#### The following are all executed WITHIN `minikube` using `minikube ssh`

This is the `image history` of the image on the remote repo:

```
IMAGE                                                                     CREATED             CREATED BY                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   SIZE      COMMENT
sha256:d6ad638d95ae5cb2c34b7f0ec51a20db177b55559b14ccdfebbf7ded540a690a   About an hour ago   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet" "/app/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.dll"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 About an hour ago   COPY /app/publish . # buildkit                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               3.84MB    buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 4 days ago          WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 4 days ago          EXPOSE map[443/tcp:{}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 4 days ago          EXPOSE map[80/tcp:{}]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 4 days ago          WORKDIR /app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0B        buildkit.dockerfile.v0
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:92bf025ac6ae2fcccb56b9250069db943d8934aa484232b9e95ab8719fbda315 in /usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App                                                                                                                             21.8MB
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV ASPNET_VERSION=7.0.5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0B
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/dotnet /usr/bin/dotnet                                                                                                                                                                                                                    24B
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) COPY dir:d047d158ec6d05333fed3029665c06808b52d4d8225a0c71387ffeda7735c7bb in /usr/share/dotnet                                                                                                                                                             73.2MB
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV DOTNET_VERSION=7.0.5                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0B
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80 DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true                                                                                                                                                                                          0B
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends         ca-certificates                 libc6         libgcc1         libgssapi-krb5-2         libicu67         libssl1.1         libstdc++6         zlib1g     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*   37MB
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop)  CMD ["bash"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0B
<missing>                                                                 12 days ago         /bin/sh -c #(nop) ADD file:11b1acca3f68b5c5787e292ff8dbdd114964a7272bf3519ab07710cbc01a0838 in /
```

and if I run `docker create --name="tmp_$$" privareREepoServer:5001/path/kubernetestestwithsecrets` and then `docker export tmp_$$ | tar -t |grep app` I get

```
app/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.deps.json
app/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.dll
app/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.pdb
app/KubernetesTestWithSecrets.runtimeconfig.json
app/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OpenApi.dll
app/Microsoft.OpenApi.dll
app/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.dll
app/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.dll
app/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.dll
app/appSettings.Development.json
app/web.config
```

and `docker export tmp_$$ | tar -t |grep 7.0.5` yields a metric ton of .net library files.

Comment: Generally you want to **not** specify `nodePort`'s in Service configs. This is because Kubernetes assigns `NodePort`'s dynamically. The Service will bind the `port`'s it exposes by using the Pod's `targetPort`.

Comment: Your configs are inconsistent. The `Dockerfile` documents using `EXPOSE` (this does not program the network) ports `80` and `443`. The Docker Compose then maps the host's (!) ports `9443` and `8000` to `80` and `9443` (!?). Is it `443` or `9443`? The Kubernetes Service then references container (`targetPort`'s) of `80` and `443` so I assume `80` and `443` are correct but you should ensure this is so.

Comment: Best practice is to use `8080` for container ports rather than e.g. `80`. You can still expose (e.g. using a Service) these ports as `80`. This is because `80` is a restricted port (ports<1024) and requires that the container be running as root. You'll probably (!?) need to run the container as root if you wish to run it using `80`.

Comment: I didn't see it, but it's helpful to look at logs. In your case, assuming your `--namespace=default`, you can `kubectl logs deployment/kubernetestestwithsecrets` and, also `kubectl describe deployment/kubernetestestwithsecrets` to see events.

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm not at the point where that concerns me. Right now the fact it fails to even execute the binary is the issue.

Comment: Ah! Missed that important part ;-) You're overwriting your DLL with the volume mount `volume-appsettings-json`

Comment: The Docker Compose also mounts into `/ssl` but the Kubernetes Deployment config is using `/app/...` with no evident config where you're specifying the different location.

Comment: The overwrite is the answer @DazWilkin -Make that an answer and I'll give you credit. What's the answer then for just adding a file into the /app folder with configMap?

Comment: If you can, it's better to mount folders. If you can't, see [`VolumeMount`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.27/#volumemount-v1-core), where `mountPath` is the path to the destination file (can have a different name)  and `subPath` is (in this case) the ConfigMap path to the source file.